# Disappearing contact photos

Tags: icloud, contacts, contacts.app

Apple's Contacts app has been acting up for me recently. About the same time that iCloud sync stopped working I noticed that when assigning photos to contacts, they don't stay saved. They appear to be saved at first but when returning to the same contact card a minute later or so, the photo is gone.

Is anyone else having this issue? Any ideas how to fix it? I'm using macOS 10.13 on a 2017 MacBook Pro and iOS 11 on an iPhone 7.

Comment: I have the exact same issue, sync stopped followed by pictures not sticking. Same OS versions as you too. Did you ever fix it ?

Comment: @xApple Not yet. I’ll try wiping the drive and clean-installing macOS this week. Will report in case that helps.

Comment: @xApple Clean-installing High Sierra indeed seems to have fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK well I tried the following:

- Turning off and on the contacts toggle switch on both the mac and the iPhone simultaneously. No effect.
- Turning off iCloud on both the mac and the iPhone simultaneously. And then on. No effect.
- Signing out of iCloud on both the mac and the iPhone simultaneously and then logging back in. This was a painful process but seemed to have solved the issue.